# Output/export information from configmgr 2012 ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, configurationmanager, sccm

I understand it is possible to export the report data into multiple file types using the export button. however i'm wanting to access the information without having to manually export. So my question is, is it possible using a batch file or powershell to read a text box on the report and output it say into a notepad file or spreadsheet. or if not maybe just a way to export all of the data on the report without having to manually do it? Screenshot attached for an example.[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a subscription for the report and either have an attachment emailed to you or have it saved to a network location.  In either case, there are several export options (csv, excel, xml, etc.).  If you're only wanting partial data from the report, I'd recommend creating a sql query or just create a new report that gets you exactly what you need.